# При передаче строки в конструктор у строки пропадают обратные слэши. Как это предотвратить?

Tags: javascript

Куда делить обратные слэши (\) ? Как передать переменную в конструктор, чтобы обратные слэши остались?

```js
Mapex = {
}
        
Mapex.MapexMap = function(str) {
    let el = document.getElementById('output');
  el.innerHTML = str;
}

let str = '<a href=\"vk.com\">vk.com</a>'
let map = new Mapex.MapexMap(str);
```

```css
#output {
  width: 220px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
ВОПРОС! Куда делить обратные слэши (\) ? Как передать переменную в конструктор, чтобы обратные слэши остались?
<br><br>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

Comment: Обратный слэш используется для экранирования спецсимволов. Замените одиночные обратные слэши на двойные. [Спецсимволы](https://learn.javascript.ru/string#spetssimvoly)

Answer (score 2):

Единственный способ передать слеши в их мета-качестве — это использовать [`String.raw()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw). Но эту функцию не получится использовать с переменной, в которой хранится строка без удвоенных слешей. Можно только использовать её как tagged template при создании переменной, что вряд ли подходит к вашему случаю. Впрочем, судите сами (в вашем исходном примере изменил только одну строку, там, где создаётся содержимое переменной `str`):

```js
Mapex = {
}
        
Mapex.MapexMap = function(str) {
    let el = document.getElementById('output');
  el.innerHTML = str;
}

let str = String.raw`<a href=\"vk.com\">vk.com</a>`
let map = new Mapex.MapexMap(str);
```

```css
#output {
  width: 220px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
ВОПРОС! Куда делить обратные слэши (\) ? Как передать переменную в конструктор, чтобы обратные слэши остались?
<br><br>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Может как-то так?

```js
Mapex = {
}
        
Mapex.MapexMap = function(str) {
    let el = document.getElementById('output');
  el.innerHTML = str;
}

let str = '<a href=\\"vk.com\\">vk.com</a>'
let map = new Mapex.MapexMap(str);
```

```css
#output {
  width: 220px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
ВОПРОС! Куда делить обратные слэши (\) ? Как передать переменную в конструктор, чтобы обратные слэши остались?
<br><br>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

Comment: А можно ли как-нибудь, не меняя строки, передать ее со слэшами? Например, в JSON превратить, передать, а потом (в конструкторе) - обратно в строку? Как еще можно? Или такие манипуляции могут повлиять на целостность данных?

Comment: @user153742 `А можно ли как-нибудь, не меняя строки, передать ее со слэшами?` в вашей строке нет слэшей. `\"` - это одиночный символ кавычки, а \\ - одиночный символ обратного слэша.